flyway 10.16.0 No database found but there is database running (mysql)
My Environment
build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.5"
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.25.0"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.6"
    id("jacoco")
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "10.16.0"
}

group = "com.wesang.walletyo"
version = "0.0.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    runtimeOnly {
        exclude(group = "commons-logging", module = "commons-logging")
    }
}

flyway {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310"
    user = "walletyo_user"
    password = "walletyo_password"
    defaultSchema = "walletyo"
    schemas = arrayOf("walletyo")
    locations = arrayOf("filesystem:migrations")
    encoding = "UTF-8"
    outOfOrder = true
    validateOnMigrate = true
    cleanDisabled = false
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql")
}

tasks.bootJar {
    // Disable bootJar execution for root project
    enabled = false
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://repo.spring.io/milestone")
    maven("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot")
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.spotless")
    apply(plugin = "io.freefair.lombok")
    apply(plugin = "jacoco")
}

I'm using java 17 and spring boot 3.3.1.
database:

What I did
I ran
./gradlew flywayMigrate --stacktrace
What happened
> Task :flywayMigrate FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  No database found to handle jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at 

...

org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:158)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:96)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.getDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:122)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1719)
        at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.configuration(FluentConfiguration.java:903)
        at org.flywaydb.gradle.task.AbstractFlywayTask.runTask(AbstractFlywayTask.java:605)
        ... 123 more


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 666ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Question
seems like password and user and database is right (I double checked), but still, flyway could not find the database. what am I missing here?
etc
stack overflow is complaining that there is too much code so I'm wrinting more...

what about 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/walletyo'?

Related issue with suggestions: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3774

I downgraded flyway to 8.2.0 and
added
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
}

(both of above are necessary)
what a ridiculous behavior!
